# MaterialUI value prop not updating after value state change with dynamic rending of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-props, react-state

Im dynamically generating material ui form components and i want to update their values when i write in the form. However the value prop is assigned to a useState values object. when i change this object and update the state, The value in the object changes correctly but the material UI component does not as its value is tied to the original value object. I believe its related to the fact the i am dynamically creating these components with a button.

The value prop in the text Field is what is not updating.

I am updating the values for these fields inside handleAnswersChange. it checks if an answer already exist. If it does it will update it. If not it will create a new one.

```
interface State {
  title: string;
  question: string;
  answers: Array<Answer>;
  correctAnswer: number;
}

interface Answer {
  answer: string;
  id: number;
}

export default function CreateQuestion() {
  const [answers, setAnswers] = React.useState<Array<JSX.Element>>([]);
  const [errorAnswer, setErrorAnswer] = React.useState(false);
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState<State>({
    title: "",
    question: "",
    answers: [{ answer: "", id: 1 }],
    correctAnswer: 1,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(values);
  }, [values]);

  const handleChange =
    (prop: any) => (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value });
    };
  const handleAnswersChange = (
    prop: any,
    id: number
  ) => (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(values.answers[0].answer);
    let answerIndex: number = 0;
    let doesExist: boolean = false;
    values.answers.map((answer, index) => {
      if (answer.id === id) {
        answerIndex = index;
        doesExist = true;
      }
    });
    if (doesExist) {
      const tempValues = values.answers;
      tempValues[answerIndex] = {
        answer: tempValues[answerIndex].answer + event.target.value,
        id: id,
      };
      setValues({
        ...values,
        [prop]: [...tempValues],
      });
    } else {
      setValues({
        ...values,
        [prop]: [...values.answers, { answer: event.target.value, id: id }],
      });
    }
  };

  const createAnswer = () => {
    const array = [...answers];
    array.push(
      <Box sx={{ m: 1 }} key={answers.length}>
        <FormControl
          sx={{ width: "60ch" }}
          variant="outlined"
          key={answers.length}
        >
          <TextField
            id="outlined-required"
            key={answers.length}
            label={"Answer " + (answers.length + 1)}
            value={values.answers[answers.length - 1].answer}
            onChange={
              handleAnswersChange("answers", values.answers.length);
            }
          />
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
```

Comment: Could you put this in a sandbox?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by sandbox. Quite new to this

Comment: Go [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and set it up so your code runs. Like a minimal example of your problem so people can take a look at it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-paper-l47i3?file=/src/theme.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong index. You map over it, but also you the same static index. So formik will put it into the wrong place.

```
handleAnswersChange(event, "answers", values.answers.length);
```

This will always select the wrong index. Since the first element will have `values.answers.length` of 1, but its index is 0.

Try it with .map and the index like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-parm-lmb4j).

Save the answers in themselves and just render them with map.

You also do not need so many keys. Just for the direct child of map.

Update:
I just saw that you are already saving the answers in the values as well, so you can simply map over `values.answers` and discard the answer array.

Comment: Thank you so much. I definitely didn't need the two arrays. And i should not have been pushing a jsx element to an array and re-renderng it. Thanks for pointing out i could use the component as a template and then just map the data over it. :D